# AngularJS Secure Storage Media

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, ng-storage

I'm developing a client-side application using AngularJS. I need to request some authorization-related data from the server-side once and store it to be used in access control decisions. I don't want to request the data before every decision.

I tried to use browser local storage, but I found it can be edited in the browser which is not acceptable in my case. I've also thought about encrypting the authorization data but as long as the encryption is done client-side, it can be reverse-engineered.

Is there a secure (read-only) storage that can hold the authorization data to suite my case?

Comment: is it a single page application? or do you want to store the information between page refreshes?

Comment: Yes, it's a single page application.

Comment: Then why not just store that information in a service and use it?

Comment: That's the case now. The problem is that it gets called almost with every state change which is too much (considering that the app will be used by hundreds of thousands). So, I need to call it once during application initialization and store it on a secure media.

Comment: You can call it once during initialization and store it as a javascript value in a service. :)

Comment: @toskv I don't see how does that solve the requirement of "if it can be edited in the browser, it is not acceptable".

Comment: well.. then your only solution is checking the user's credentials on every request. because everything in the browser can be edited by the user. :(

Comment: what you can do is make it convenient for yourself by making the $http service send it as a request header on every request.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending your data to the client, an environment you have no control over. What you can do *at most* is make it inconvenient for them to modify it.

To make it impossible to modify? You cannot do that. *(Think of the problem abstractly: what you're trying to do is forbid the user to do some operations on his own device.)*

That is why all kinds of security-related functions need to stay on the backend (an environment in your control), or at least include a backend component.

In your specific case, think of handling the view privileges on the client side as a usability feature: you don't want to direct your user to pages they are not supposed to see, but it is the backend's responsibility to only serve data they are actually allowed to access. So in case you have a malicious user who goes "where he's not supposed to", it'll be up to the backend to not send them data he's not supposed to see.

Comment: I already have most of the access control decisions on the backend. I only need to manage view privileges client-side

Comment: @YAM whatever you store on the client-side the client will be able to modify. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: I see. I'm just wondering what are the best practices for this case? Just calling the service with every request?

Comment: adding your credentials to every request as an http header, and checking that header on the server would do.

Comment: @YAM best practices are an entirely different, and a subjective issue, you should probably open a separate question for that. (If it's a theoretical discussion, maybe it's better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), if you want to get an opinion on a certain implementation, for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).